# case auto response rules not working in developer sandbox

Tags: case, email2case, case-auto-response

I have many case auto response rules setup in my salesforce org.
All the rules are working fine in production and full copy sandboxes but when it comes to developer or developer pro sandboxes, none of the rules work.
The email deliverability is set to 'All Email' so user does receive all other email notifications coming from other processes/workflow rules.

Anybody has any information as to why the case auto response rules are not working in developer and developer pro sandboxes?

Comment: Did you check the email address? The users email address is always get changed in sandbox when the sandbox is refreshed or created and even if your email deliverability is set to All Email, the email will not be delivered since the email address does not exist.

Comment: Well that is the first thing i checked and its fine which i mentioned in the question that the user is receiving all other email notifications